# Having trouble recasting WifiManager to Object in Android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

So I am quite new to Android, and have limited previous Java experience, so please bear with me. I am trying to create an object of type WifiManager in an Android App, and I have the line I found several other people recommend to create a WifiManager object verbatum:

```
WifiManager wifi =  mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

in my program. Now Eclipse has underlined the mContext.GetSystemService etc part with the error **Type mismatch, cannot convert from object to WifiManager**

Now I have tried recasting the return using:

```
(WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

This will compile, but results in a **java.lang.NullPointerException** when executed

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE***

SO I have setup the

```
Context mContext;
```

in my main class

Then I am trying to use a broadcast to find the address of a SQL server on my network. The code is kinda messy since I am just in the phase where I am trying to get just transmitting the broadcast to work. But here is the function.

```
public void findSQL()
{
    int PORT = 1433;

    try
    {
        byte buff[] = new byte[1024];
        DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket(PORT); 
        sock.setBroadcast(true);

        // Create and send the broadcast packet
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buff, 7, getBroadcastAddress(), PORT);

        sock.send(dp);

        DatagramPacket dp1 = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length);

        sock.receive(dp1);

        sock.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {  
    WifiManager wifi =  (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();

    System.out.println(dhcp.toString());

    if(dhcp==null)
        return InetAddress.getByAddress(null);

    int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;

    byte[] quads = new byte[4];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
    {
        quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
    }

    return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
}
```

**SECOND EDIT***

Earlier in my code I have defined:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
class MSSQL_DB
{
    Context mContext;
    public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string, 
            String db_userid, String db_password)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string,
                    db_userid, db_password);
            System.out.println("Connected");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am afraid the whole concept of what "context" actually does, how to declare it correctly, and how to use its methods is what I must not be fully understanding yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably ur mContext is null..  If not

Please post more logs of exception.. and post more code ...

Comment: I have posted more code now. See if that helps. And as for the exception, there isnt much more to tell.. It just says its a null pointer issue, which leads me to believe that there is some sort of problem recasting an Object to WifiManager. Which since WifiManager extends type object seems a little odd to me!

Comment: As I said. U don't. Assigning mcontext =this.getapplicationcontext in on create method

Comment: Oh no. I dont define Context mContext in my function. I defined it class wide. It was throwing errors about mContext not being defined before I tried that. I tried moving it into the function, but that did not help. This is a problem with the WifiManager object not recasting the return from mContext.getSystemService() being in the form of a object not a WifiManager object. Do you think that using the line mContext = this.getapplicationcontext would be a better approach than mContext Context; for some reason?

Comment: Dude...  Where have u initialized mContext object.. show me the code of this

Comment: This is not the problem of WiFimanager ; ur logics is the main prob. U don't know what does define means.. u are not defining mContext u are declaring it.. define it and it will work properly. mContext is null here.. and dis is the prob

Comment: Ankit, thank you for your help. You are right, like I said I am quite new to this, and the whole concept of the Context is what I am still learning about. I have added how I *THOUGHT* I was declaring my context. You are correct I get the null pointer exception if I try to check the contents of mContext. So I guess my whole question can be rephrased into "how do I define mContext" correctly.

Comment: I said you need mContext = this; if you are in activity or service. thats it...
then it will work well..Sorry if it makes you feel bad.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat] I will help you to solve this.(http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13889/discussion-between-ankit-and-dynamphorous)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE in your manifest?

Comment: I had not had it, but even with it I still get the same exact error message. I had the ACCESS_INTERNET permissions but not WIFI_STATE. Now I have both and nothing has changed. It seems to be a recasting the object to WifiManager that is the real problem.

Comment: If you throw a breakpoint onto that line, what is the value of mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

Comment: I tried debugging by allowing mContext.getsystemService(Context.WIFI...etc)  to cast itself as a Object, then trying to do object.toString() to verify what it was doing, but that also crashed. I'm embarrassed to say I'm VERY new to this and dont know how to use breakpoints with the android emulator. Normal breakpoints just stop the system from ever loading the compiled program into the emulator.

Comment: Eclipse version 4.2 Juno

Comment: Hmm.. and if you throw a breakpoint on mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); it doesn't break?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13871/discussion-between-neil-d-and-dynamphorous)